# Get the populated data associated with ref in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two schemas: 'Leads' and 'LeadsCategory'.

**Leads Schema:**

```
const id = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const leadsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: id,
    userId: { type: id, ref: "User", required: true },
    leadName: String,
    leads: [
      {
        _id: id,
        name: String,
        mobile: Number,
        address: String,
        education: {
          school: String,
          graduation: String
        },
        leadType: { type: id, ref: "LeadsCategory", required: true }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("lead", leadsSchema);
```

**Leads Category Schema:**

```
const id = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const leadsCategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: id,
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    leadsData: [{ type: id, ref: 'lead' }]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("LeadsCategory", leadsCategorySchema);
```

I'm referencing the leadsCategory as soon as new lead is created and it does populate my leadsCategory into the **Leads controller**.

So my final data inside 'Leads collection' looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e8832dde5d8273824d86502",
        "leadName": "Freshers",
        "leads": [
            {
                "education": {
                    "school": "LPS",
                    "graduation": "some school"
                },
                "location": {
                    "state": "delhi",
                    "country": "india"
                },
                "name": "Joey",
                "mobile": 1524524678,
                "_id": "5e8832dde5d8273824d86500",
                "leadType": {
                    "_id": "5e88285f5dda5321bcc045a6",
                    "name": "all"
                }
            },
            {
                "education": {
                    "school": "DAV",
                    "graduation": "some school"
                },
                "location": {
                    "state": "delhi",
                    "country": "india"
                },
                "name": "Ben",
                "mobile": 1524524678,
                "_id": "5e8832dde5d8273824d86501",
                "leadType": {
                    "_id": "5e88285f5dda5321bcc045a6",
                    "name": "all"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But now I need to associate the leads data into my 'leadsCategory' collection so that I can query the leads data according to the leadType created. For now, I have only one 'leadType':'all'. But further, I will create more types and populate the data accordingly.

I tried something like this:

```
exports.get_leads_type_all = (req, res) => {
  LeadsCategory.find()
  .populate('leadsData')
  .then( data => {
    res.json(data)
  })
}
```

But this returns me only empty array like this:

```
    {       "leadsData": [],
        "_id": "5e88285f5dda5321bcc045a6",
        "name": "all",
        "createdAt": "2020-04-04T06:25:35.171Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-04T06:25:35.171Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Please help me to associate and related this data. I have tried lot's of thins but could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
exports.get_leads_type_all = (req, res) => {
  LeadsCategory.find()
  .populate('leadsData')
  .execPopulate()
  .then( data => {
    res.json(data)
  })
}
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-execPopulate